# Editing Job and DTS on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I took over a SQL Server 2000 and need to fix a job that calls 3 DTS packages. How can I cross reference the DTSRun hash to the actual DTS name?

Answer (score 1):

[DTSRunDec](http://jimmers.info/software.html) should be the answer for you. Pass the DTSRun hash to the utility.

Answer (score 0):

We use something like the following for the command (in the job step properties)

```
DTSRun /S <servername> /E /N <dts package name>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by cross reference, so this may not be an appropriate answer.